# mount external drive on windows7 for git

Tags: msysgit

I love my GitBash window because it helps maintain the illusion that I am not on Windows 7. I can type `ls /c/` and see `C:/`. This has worked fine for me.  Now I would like to create a git backup on an external drive that is not underneath C:.  I plug in the drive, Windows assigned it "G:" but now, how do I tell Mingw32 to know about it?

I'd like to use  **`$ git remote add backup /tmp/backup`**  from [this excellent answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1887364/git-clone-to-external-drive-for-backup#answer-1887474) but change `/tmp` to `G:`

```
$ git remote add backup /G/myrepo  ...
$ git push backup
fatal: 'C:/prog/Git/G/myrepo' does not appear to be a git repository
fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly
```

I'm not sure what information is useful.

```
$ git --version
git version 1.7.0.2.msysgit.0
$ ls G:
ls: G:: No such file or directory
```

Comment: Why are you fighting your OS?

Comment: you are aware that by adding the git bin dir to the PATH you can just use cmd and type stuff like `git remote add g:/myrepo` ?

Comment: I'm not sure what you are saying. git's bin is in my PATH but I couldn't get "ls G:/" to work.  Thanks.

Comment: in the windows command line it's not ls but `dir g:`

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Go to Disk Management in Computer Management, right-click the drive in question, click Change Drive Letters and Paths, and mount it to a folder in your `C:` drive.

Comment: thank you.  I don't want to tell you how long I googled around to try to figure this out.

Comment: You're welcome.  [You should accept this answer by clicking the hollow check](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work).

Answer (score 6):

Git Bash doesn't dynamically "mount" drives, so you need to close all Git Bash instances, then start a new instance. It should then appear under `/g`.

Source: http://comments.gmane.org/gmane.comp.version-control.msysgit/13133